# Check if py file is run by ide or command line

Tags: python-3.x

I need to check if my python unittest script is run by Visual studio test explorer, or if it is run by command line. Is there anything more than if len(sys.argv) >= 1?

Comment: I would start with checking env variables when the tests are running by VS test explorer. Checking sys.argv is not the right approach as you may run these tests from command line with several arguments.

Comment: Why is it important to know?

Comment: another way to go is by os.getppid() get the pid of your unittest script instance  parent, then you can try to do a little wrapping on  [find process name via pid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211427/find-process-name-by-its-process-id)

Comment: i need to run two test siutes, one when it is run by VS, and second, when tests are run from jenkins job

Comment: You shouldn't tightly couple your tests to your IDE or a particular CI environment. Sounds like you need a proper feature-flag/config-file

Answer (score 3):

Look in `os.environ.keys()` for Visual Studio specific environment variables that are only present when running inside VS. See [Detect where Python code is running (e.g., in Spyder interpreter vs. IDLE vs. cmd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728395/detect-where-python-code-is-running-e-g-in-spyder-interpreter-vs-idle-vs-cm)